# Jquery If structure not working as expected

Tags: jquery

```
$('#myClick2').click(function () {
                var value = $(this).val();
                If (value != 'on') {
                    $.getJSON('message_center_getMessageLists.asp', {}, function (json) {
                        alert(json.one);
                        alert(json.two);
                        alert(json.three);
                    })
                    .error(function () { alert("There was an error while trying to make this request;  If it persists please contact support"); });
                }
            });
```

The $.getJSON part was working just fine until I wrapped the IF statement around it.  I am trying to get the check box to execute the .getJSON only if it is not currently checked.  Anyone have any idea what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: It is <input id="myClick2" type="checkbox" name="rank2">

Comment: You may want to use `.change` instead of `.click`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"...execute the .getJSON only if it is not currently checked"*

Then do it like this...

```
if (!this.checked) {
    $.getJSON(...
```

Comment: I had to do (this.checked) to get it to work on the first click (checking the box) and not to work on the second click (unchecking the box).  But this worked like a charm, you guys rock!

Comment: @JamesWilson: Yes, the handler will fire after the change of state, so its current state will be opposite of its initial state. :)

Comment: I am pretty new to Jquery, is there a performance or other reason to use .change over .click?

Comment: @JamesWilson: The `change` event occurs when there's a change of state in the checkbox. The `click` even occurs when the user performs a mouse click on the checkbox. It's possible to change the state of a box without clicking it. Now I'd guess that most browsers probably still invoke the `click` event when a `change` event happens *(event if it wasn't clicked)*, but to be safe, I'd bind to the event that you're actually interested in.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, will make sure use those from now on when i am looking for them to change state.

Answer (score 2):

You `if` statement is capitalized. Change it to lowercase and that should fix your problem.

Also are you sure that the `value` is in fact not equal to `on`?

**UPDATE**

Then what you want to do is use `this.checked` in the if statement.

Comment: That fixed one issue, now it seems another has cropped up.  I can use firbug to grab the value when it is checked and it shows it as on.  but the function doesn't seem to respect that. <input id="myClick2" type="checkbox" name="rank2">

Comment: @JamesWilson Hey I updated my answer for you. See if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

`.val()` returns the value of the `value` attribute.

You want `if (this.checked)` (no jQuery) or `if ($(this).is(':checked'))`